# How to export vector layer's legend separately in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, legend

I have a vector layer with `QgsRendererRangeV2()` objects. I searched to get legend belongs to the vector layer and found this:

```
legend = QgsComposerLegend(c)
legend.model().setLayerSet(mapRenderer.layerSet())
c.addItem(legend)
```

which attaches the legend to the left-top corner of the map plot. But I want to get the legend as a separate image.